# POST Method in php

Tags: php, post, methods

I don't know how to deal with the error. i just want to pass the value to another page. i use "GET" method , it is okay. However, it is not working with "POST" method.

The error :
Undefined index: data in C:\Users\x\x\x\x\x on line 18

**Testing.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

 <form method="POST" action="testing.php">
  <input name="data" type="text">
  <input type ="submit" value="send">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**testing.php**

```
<?php

$data = $_REQUEST["data"];
if (isset($data)) {
    echo $data;
}
else
{
    echo "No data ";
}

?>
```

Comment: Check that you have the attribute name as data on your input form as above.  It's easy to accidentally use id instead of name.

Answer (score 0):

This example **does work** - irrelevant of the send method (GET / POST).
These cases are handled (and you possibly should too):

- Variable "data" NOT TRANSMITTED.
- Variable "data" transmitted BUT EMPTY
- Variable "data" transmitted and HAS CONTENTS

### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="testing.php">
        <input name="data" type="text">
        <input type ="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP script

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST["data"])) {
    $data = trim($_REQUEST["data"]);
    if (strlen($data) > 0) {
        echo "Data sent: $data";
    } else {
        echo "Data sent but EMPTY";
    }
} else {
    echo "NO DATA sent";
}

?>
```

### Result

Either one of...

`NO DATA sent`
`Data sent: myData`
`Data sent but EMPTY`

Comment: i try it in notepad++, it works.... but try in phpstorm (php intellij) , it fails...

Comment: @soul299 file encoding issue?

Comment: **I don't think it's an encoding problem**. Oviously the parameter $_POST['data'] was not transmitted as it should be. Based on your code I cannot say why. And in consequence, the PHP script found "data" to be undefined. Encoding has to do with the character set (latin1, utf-8, etc.), and would produce unreadable characters when not matching, but it would work anyway. The editor could have inserted a character e.g. in the name of the input field, though. I have seen similar effects also.

Comment: BTW, _if (isset($data)) {_ would also be true if the data field where empty. But in this case you would not get an error message from PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You can't assign it to a local variable before checking if it is present. You need to call `isset` on the actual thing you care about:

```
if (isset($_POST["data"])) {
    $data = $_POST["data"];
```

Comment: this time, no error message shown , but i still cannot pass the data value to another page

Comment: No, because I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: just want to pass the data value to another page by using POST method ....    the problem is that i cannot pass the value only..

Comment: Is this "other page" a PHP script or is it HTML code that contains a form again, or....?

Comment: i just want to obtain the value from html "Data"  in testing.php

Comment: if i type the username(data) in testing.html   ,   it will show me the username in testing.php     that's all.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$data=trim($_POST['data']);

if(empty($data){
    echo "no data";
} else {
    echo $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: I meant edit the code, use indentation, make it easier to read. I did it for you

Answer (score -1):

IMHO you should check if data is actually being passed or not. change your php as below:

```
 <?php 
 $data = (isset($_REQUEST["data"]) && $_REQUEST["data"] != "") ? $_REQUEST["data"]: "no data" ;
 echo $data;
 //this should print value of data (or "no data" if no value passed)
 ?>
```